# How do I use the FreeBusyResponse in Google Calendar java API?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to determine if the logged in user is free at a given time. So far I've managed to get a FreeBusyResponse, using this code.

```
String dIn = "2015-09-10 19:00:00";
String dIne = "2015-09-10 20:00:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Date d = df.parse(dIn);
DateTime startTime = new DateTime(d, TimeZone.getDefault());

Date de = df.parse(dIne);
DateTime endTime = new DateTime(de, TimeZone.getDefault())

FreeBusyRequest req = new FreeBusyRequest();
req.setTimeMin(startTime);
req.setTimeMax(endTime);
Freebusy.Query fbq = client.freebusy().query(req);

FreeBusyResponse fbresponse = fbq.execute();
System.out.println(fbresponse.toString());
```

This prints

```
{"kind":"calendar#freeBusy","timeMax":"2015-09-10T10:00:00.000Z","timeMin":"2015-09-10T09:00:00.000Z"}
```

All I want is a boolean yes/no response for if the user is busy.

Am I using FreeBusy in the wrong context? I'm new to using google's APIs and still relatively noobish in Java as well, so apologies if the answer is obvious.

Comment: While sending request req.setTimeMin(startTime);
req.setTimeMax(endTime); to freebusy.query, if you send items .id--> which is the calendar id from which you want to retreive the free/busy info, then in the response you will get "busy": [
        {
          "start": datetime,
          "end": datetime
        } which indicates calendar is busy from starting above date to ending date you get in the response. But you dont get any information in true/ false.

Comment: @SGC Thank you! That helped put me on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While sending request req.setTimeMin(startTime); req.setTimeMax(endTime); to freebusy.query, if you send items .id--> which is the calendar id from which you want to retreive the free/busy info, then in the response you will get "busy": [ { "start": datetime, "end": datetime } which indicates calendar is busy from starting above date to ending date you get in the response. But you dont get any information in true/ false.